# How to add all sub-totals to get a grand total price in mvc5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Right now i am making a subtotal with quantity * Unit price

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        String subTotal = Convert.ToDouble(Convert.ToDouble(item.Quantity) * Convert.ToDouble(item.UnitCost)).ToString("#0.00");

}
```

but now i want to make a Grandtotal by adding all the sub totals

I had no idea what i was doing what i tried this and it didn't work

```
foreach(sub in subtotal){

    String Grandtotal = subtotal + subtotal

}
```

I am also new to MVC any help will be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double grandTotal = 0;
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        double subTotal = Convert.ToDouble(item.Quantity) * Convert.ToDouble(item.UnitCost);
        grandTotal += subTotal;

}

string formattedGrandTotal = grandTotal.ToString("#0.00");
```